# css keyframe position issue

Tags: html, css, resolution, screen-size, keyframe

I want to know how to set the resolution size on key frames, there is a bubble on my website which falls from the top to the bottom. I have set it properly for my screen size but I notice that when screen size changes the bubble go more down and create white space. It is definitely because i set it as top:-500px and top:500px so in every screen size it is taking 500px as fixed height. i want to set top:500px in such a way that whenever size changes it should take the screen height and should stop at bottom.
i tried some code but did not succeed can you please check:

```
.x4 {
    left: 1025px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.3;
    width:315px;
  height:315px;
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 15s linear forwards , sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 15s linear forwards , sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 15s linear forwards , sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
      background-image: url(http://dubaiconfident.com/confi-logo/grey1-bubble.png);
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {
        top: -500px;
    }
   100% {
        top: 500px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it okay for a simple javascript solution

Comment: Create a jsfiddle of your codes.

Comment: use `%` instead of `px`

Comment: Take a look at css calc property: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/03/CSS-layout-gets-smarter-with-calc?hl=en

Comment: here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tqjrego6/ please check by resizing screen it takes speacfic height

Comment: Anybody knows this?

Answer (score 0):

Use your moving element with `position:fixed` and `top` property with **percents** as units instead of **pixels** (so, start position `0%`, end `100%-height of element`) . Of course, parent of your element would have to be `body` for this.

---

If you would like to have more control over css keyframes, set them to be responsive, dynamically generate and re-generate them, use tool like [jQuery.Keyframes](https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes)

Comment: No its not helping i made it @-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {
        top: 0%;
    }
   100% {
        top: 100%;
    }
}
 this takes the bubble i don't know where in the bottom:(

Comment: Not entire 100% for top; it would push your element behind bottom margin of viewport, try with less percentages.

Comment: you can use `-100%` or even `-200%`

Comment: i tried that as -64% but it is taking as a specific height @-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% {
        top: -100%;
    }
   100% {
        top: 64%;
    }
}

Comment: then again on resizing screen the position changes

Comment: please check fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/tqjrego6/  try resizing image it goes in the bottom on each resize

Answer (score 0):

Try below codes and use `media query` to make that work properly on other screen resolution, you can use `vh (viewport height)` or `% (percentage)` to set landing or stopping of that bubble.

```css
.x4 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.3;
    left:calc(100% - 75%);
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 5s linear forwards;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 5s;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 5s;
      background-image: url(http://dubaiconfident.com/confi-logo/grey1-bubble.png);
      background-size:100% 100%;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      position:relative;
      width:320px;
      height:320px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
    0%{
        top: -50vh;
    }
   100% {
        top: 30vh;
    }
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
.x4 {
    left:calc(100% - 70%);
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds {
    0%{
        top: -50vh;
    }
   100% {
        top: 30vh;
    }
}  
}
```

```html
<div class="x4">

</div>
```

Comment: No Not working bubble goes to the bottom and create white space and then bubble disappers :(

Comment: @NS123 it stops at center of page that's why everything below it will be white space, where you want it to be and it doesn't disappears. Change in keyframe animation 100% top value according to your plans from 30vh to 60 or 100vh.

Comment: it should stop at the bottom of page. and no matter whatever the screen size is according to that it should stop at the bottom.